# Preserve ICC color profile on image transformations

Tags: image-transforms, image

Is it possible to configure Craft to preserve the ICC color profile?

I did test JPG images saved in "sRGB IEC61966-2.1" profile and the files returned from Craft transformations are always saved in plain "RGB", oversaturated and just not as nice.

Imagick is installed.

Comment: Are you using GD2 or Imagick on your server? GD2 has absolutely no support for color profiles. Imagick has, so unless you've already tried it, check if that helps. But I guess the question is still, whether Craft preserves it or not.

Comment: Imagick is installed and Craft uses it. EXIF data etc. is preserved but the ICC is not. Check this because I guessed Craft transform uses Imagick's `stripImage()` method, that does not only remove EXIF but also the ICC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Not currently, but this is already on our list.</s>

The image processing library we're using only recently (within the last 6 months or so) added ICC profile support.

**Update:**

Great news for all photographers and image lovers! Things changed with Craft 2.3, ICC profiles are now preserved if Imagick is installed and used for the transformation.

Comment: Thanks Brad, looking forward to it. Quality images is essential for photography / art portfolios.

Comment: Yes, this is really great news! Thanks Brad.